# Linked list - insert function

Tags: c, linked-list

Good Day All,

I try to prepare a student info system with linked list.  I created a scturct named course.  For inserting process; I will call void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, char* code)  in function main. When I compile, I see these errors; incompatible type for arg 2 of "insertCourse". Too few arguments to function "insertCourse". Does anyone comment on this issue ?  Many thanks..

```
/* Function Prototypes */
void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, char* code);

/* Main func starts here */

int main(void)
Course course_code; 


switch (choice) {
             case 1: 
                  insertCourse(&startPtr, course_code);
                  break;



/* Insert course function  */
void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, char* code)
{
CourseNodePtr newPtr;   /* New node pointer */
CourseNodePtr previousPtr;   /* previous node pointer in list */
CourseNodePtr currentPtr;    /* current node pointer in list */

newPtr = malloc( sizeof(Course) );   /* memory allocation for new node */

if (newPtr != NULL) {
           printf("Pls enter the code number of the course.\n");
           scanf("%s", &(newPtr->code));
           printf("Pls enter the course name.\n"); 
           scanf("%s", &(newPtr->name));
           printf("Pls enter the instructor name.\n"); 
           scanf("%s", &(newPtr->instructor));
           printf("Pls enter the term; Spring or Fall.\n"); 
           scanf("%s", &(newPtr->term));
           printf("Pls enter the year.\n"); 
           scanf("%s", &(newPtr->year));
           newPtr->coursePtr = NULL; 

           previousPtr = NULL; 
           currentPtr = *cr; 

           while ((currentPtr != NULL)  && ( code  > currentPtr->code)) {
                 previousPtr = currentPtr; 
                 currentPtr = currentPtr->coursePtr; 
           }  /* End While */

           if ( previousPtr == NULL ) {
                newPtr->coursePtr = *cr; 
                *cr = newPtr; 
           }   /* End if */
           else {
                previousPtr->coursePtr = newPtr; 
                newPtr->coursePtr = currentPtr; 
           }  /* End else */
    } /* End if */

    else {
         printf( " %c could not be inserted. Memory not enough...\n", code); 
    }  /* End else */
} /* End function insert */
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `course_code` as `Course`

```
Course course_code;
```

And call the `insertCourse()`

```
insertCourse(&startPtr, course_code);
```

But it's arguments must be `CourseNodePtr*` and `char*`

```
void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, char* code)
```

You passing second parameter with incorrect type. It must be `Course`

```
void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, Course code)
```

Comment: insertCourse(&startPtr, char* code);  it is giving syntax error before "char" now.

Comment: `insertCourse(&startPtr, course_code);` - this must not be changed

Comment: @Behzat, replace function prototype: `void insertCourse(CourseNodePtr* cr, Course code);` and function definition to the same as prototype.

Comment: I can not change functions; I described a char *code in main and called the functions as insertCourse(&startPtr, code); still giving syntax error..

Answer (score 0):

Second param of insertCourse expects type `*char` and you are passing type `Course`

```
insertCourse(&startPtr, course_code);
------------------------^ here
```

Comment: I tried with insertCourse(&startPtr, char* code) in main;  but it says syntax error before "char" now..

Comment: It is not allowed to change functions, sorry David. I need to create a course structure with linked list. Then I will create a student structure which will reach course structure by *coursePtr. I believe linked list is ok but I do not know how to call insert function from main..

Comment: In order to use insertCourse(&startPtr, code); what I need to describe in main function. code should not be Course type because I can not assign another type. Do I need to describe char* code = "UBI501";  in main before  function call ?

Comment: Or you can `insertCourse(&startPtr, "UBI501");` also note that you can not compare strings using `code  > currentPtr->code` use `strcmp` instead